# Vertex AIでテキスト分類（マルチラベル）用にデータをインポートしたところ「AnnotationSpec display name is required」とエラー文がでた

Tags: google-cloud, google-cloud-platform

Vertex AIでテキスト分類（マルチラベル）を行うべくデータをインポートしたところ、下記のエラーが出ました。

「Warning: AnnotationSpec display name is required. for: gs://（ファイル名）.csv line 46」
「Warning: AnnotationSpec display name is required. for: gs://（ファイル名）.csv line 124」
「Warning: AnnotationSpec display name is required. for: gs://（ファイル名）.csv line 20」
「Warning: AnnotationSpec display name is required. for: gs://（ファイル名）.csv line 527」

該当するlineも含め、データ自体は問題なくインポートできているように表示されており
また、メール内には「Error Messages: OK」と記載されています。

ここで質問です。

1. このエラーはどのような状態の際に起こってしまうものなのでしょうか？
2. このエラーの対処方法はありますでしょうか？
3. エラーの状態のままでもトレーニングやデプロイへ進めそうなのですが、問題ありますでしょうか？

宜しくお願いします。